# Is there a way to implement cassandra "decimal" Datatype in Golang

Tags: database, go, cassandra, abstract-data-type

I have a database field that is set to decimal, while in my Go project I am having problem choosing which datatype can be used.
each time I send a create reuquest to my code, I get a "cannot marshal 'decimal' into #golang datatype#

this is my database schema

```
CREATE TABLE transaction(
organization_id timeuuid,
month text,
employee_id timeuuid,
id timeuuid,
employee_name text,
amount decimal,
deductions int,
date_approved date,
PRIMARY KEY ((organization_id, month), id)
```

)

my golang models looks like this

```
type WageGarnishment struct {
ID            gocql.UUID `json:"id"`
organizationID            gocql.UUID `json:"organization_id"`
Month          string     `json:"month"`
Amount        Float64    `json:"amount"`
Deductions    uint       `json:"deductions"`
EffectiveDate time.Time  `json:"effective_date"`
DateApproved  time.Time  `json:"date_approved"`
EmployeeSummary
```

}

no matter the datatype in my Amount Field I keep getting this Error:

```
Error #01: can not marshal float64 into decimal
```

Thanks for your Help in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into [documentation for Gocql package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gocql/gocql#Marshal), then you will see that the `decimal` is mapped to the Go's `infDec` data type (see [its doc](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/inf.v0)) so you need to use it instead of `Float64`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now am getting an error
 `Error #01: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field WageGarnishment.amount of type *inf.Dec`

Comment: You need to write an adapter function that will convert `inf.Dec` into type supported by JSON. For example, format it as string